# How to disable next 7 dates from current date in Android CalendarView?

Tags: java, android, calendarview

Is there any way to disable next 7 dates from current date in Android CalendarView ?

```
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE , Calendar.getInstance().getMinimum(Calendar.DATE));
        long date = calendar.getTime().getTime();
        mCalendarView.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);


        mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                String date = (i1 + 1) + "/" + i2 + "/" + i;
                Intent intent = new Intent(CalendarPage.this, ArrangePage.class);
                intent.putExtra("date", date);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
```